# what google registration id is

Tags: android, registration, google-play

I am using google registration id in Google cloud messaging for exemple, but I don't understand how this id is generated.

Id it link to the google play account or to the mobile ?

for exemple did two different mobiles using the same google play account will have the same registration id

If a user use two google play accounts, did the registration id will depend of the google play session ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GCM Registration id is unique to an android login & the device. If a user signs in to 2 devices using the same login, they will have different GCM Ids. Found the below from this [link](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

`An ID issued by the GCM servers to the Android application that allows it to receive messages. Once the Android application has the registration ID, it sends it to the 3rd-party application server, which uses it to identify each device that has registered to receive messages for a given Android application. In other words, a registration ID is tied to a particular Android application running on a particular device.`